# Migrating from Java Calendar to Joda Date Time

Tags: java, jodatime

Previously, when I first design a stock application related software, I decide to use `java.util.Date` to represent date/time information of a stock.

Later, I realize most of the methods in `java.util.Date` is deprecated. Hence, very soon, I refactor all my code to make use of `java.util.Calendar`

However, there is 2 shortcomings I encounter.

1. Construct `java.util.Calendar` is comparative slower than `java.util.Date`
2. Within the accessors getCalendar method of `Stock` class, I need to clone a copy, as `Calendar` is a mutable class

Here is the current source code for [Stock.java](http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/jstock/src/org/yccheok/jstock/engine/Stock.java?revision=1.18&view=markup)

Recently, I discover [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). I do the following benchmarking, by creating 1,000,000 `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` and `org.joda.time.DateTime`. I found `org.joda.time.DateTime` performs better than `java.util.Calendar`, during instantiation.

Here is the benchmarking[image] result.

This instantiation speed is important, especially many instance of Stocks will be created, to represent a long price history of a stock.

Do you think is it worth to migrate from Java Calendar to Joda Date Time, to gain application speed performance? Is there any trap I need to pay attention to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that `java.util.Date` is mutable too - so if it's a problem now you're using `Calendar`, it would have been a problem using `Date` too. That said, using Joda Time is *definitely* worth doing just because it's a much, much better API.

How certain are you that performance is *actually* an issue in your particular app? You say there will be "many instances" of `Stock` created... how many? Have you profiled it? I wouldn't expect it to actually make a significant difference in most situations. It's not obvious from your benchmarking graph what you're actually measuring.

Moving to Joda Time is a good idea in general, but I would measure the performance to see how much difference it *really* makes for you.

Comment: +1 @Yan Cheng: Note also that the immutability of Joda Time's constructs can help you with performance since you can give out references to immutable objects freely without worrying about the possibility of clients mutating them. For example, where your `getCalendar()` method in `Stock` clones the `Calendar`, you could just return a Joda Time object directly.

Answer (score 3):

If `java.util.Calendar` instances to be replaced with `org.joda.time.DateTime` are *parsed and/or formatted to a particular pattern*, e.g.

```
String format = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

1. Within method signatures for parameter and return types, as well as variable declarations

and instantiations, repace *whole word* occurrences of the class names `Calendar` (with

`DateTime`) and `SimpleDateFormat` (with `DateTimeFormatter`), respectively

2. Replace the formatter instantiation statement, e.g.

   ```
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
   ```

   with

   ```
   formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
   ```
3. Replace calls to methods of `SimpleDateFormat', e.g.

   ```
   String dateStr = formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
   ```

   with

   ```
   String dateStr = DateTime.now().toString(formatter);
   ```

   and

   ```
   formatter.parse(dateStr);
   ```

   with

   ```
   DateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a `Calendar` in your `Stock` class? I think using a `Date` to represent a point in time is fine. This seems to be what you want, because you want the `Calendar` object in the a stock to be immutable, which the `Date` class should be, if you ignore the deprecated methods.

You can use a temporary `Calendar` when you need to do time operations on a `Date` outside the `Stock` class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(stock.getDate());
System.out.println(calendar.getYear());
```

Like this you can still store a `Date` in your `Stock` class, which should have the best performance when only store and retrieve `Stock` objects from a data storage. If you do several operations at once you can also reuse the same `Calendar` object.

If you don't like the `Calendar` interface you could still use Joda Time to do the time operations. You can probably convert dates to and from Joda Time if needed, to do time operations, and still store `Date` objects in your `Stock` class.

Comment: -1 stock class should be immutable. Performing date related operation will be very inconvenient. Imagine you have to getInstance and setTime everytime, all over your entire code.

Comment: Simple operation such as getYear, getMonth from Date already deprecated. If I store as Date, to perform such simple operation, I have to use create another Calendar from Date, and getYear, getMonth from Calendar.

Comment: I see no reason why you can not use a temporary Calendar for it, except that you are lazy. Java classes like SimpleDateFormat use a Calendar internally too, to get the values they have to replace in the Date pattern. If creating new Calendar objects is slow, you can always reuse a Calendar. The operations in the Date class are depreciated because they don't take timezones into account.

Comment: That's glorification. Laziness is the 1st Virtues of a Programmer, defined by Larry Wall. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer

Comment: + 1 This is absolutely correct. `Date` holds the data, `Calendar` is used for calculations. If you need to modify the dates all over your code, it is an architectural problem. Using `Calendar` instead of `Date` for holding your data is like carrying 3 calculators in your pocket just to remember 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I used Joda in the past, and it is an awesome library.

In terms of performance, you'll have to test it, unfortunately. But refactoring your code seems too much. Personally, I used `Date` throughout my whole application (including DB store and retrieve), and used Joda only when I needed data manipulation. Joda calculates fields only when needed, so I guess the overhead will be much lower than using Java API classes; furthermore, you won't have object version issues to transfer and handle `Date` objects in your DB, serialize objects and such. I don't expect Joda to break such compatibility, but it is less likely using `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to move to joda-time in general. But it it is really worth to move to the joda-time for your project is based on your use-cases pertaining to the date usage. Look at slide number 46 in the presentation for performance related numbers for some of the operations[link text](http://amap.cantabria.es/confluence/download/attachments/3244089/JodaTime-StephenColebourne.pdf?version=1)

Comment: That link is dead; can you please add or summarize the content inline?