# Android - can't export apk with Proguard, when using Joda Time

Tags: android, proguard, jodatime

I use **joda-time.jar** in my app, and when exporting signed apk proguard saying something like (it is pretty common problem as I can see, when I look over internet):

```
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
...
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] Warning: there were 37 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-01-07 12:44:53 - XYZ]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Everywhere in forums or also here ([Android - Proguard didn't compile with Joda Time jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753988/android-proguard-didnt-compile-with-joda-time-jar-file)) they say solution should be downloading **joda-convert.jar**, adding to buildpath. But for me it just DOESN'T WORK, after I did it, proguard again says something similar:

```
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter$9: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter$9: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ] Warning: org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter$9: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-01-07 12:41:39 - XYZ]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How to fix this issue? I spend few hours of trying everything, but I just can't find it out...Many thanks!

Comment: I somedays ago took a wonderful decision, by not using Joda in Android environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696044/a-generic-method-to-handle-dates-without-the-year-field

Comment: thanks, but I must use it, as I use complex date operations in my app and joda time is in my benchmarks much faster than using default java Calendar class which is in my opinion too heavy-weighted ;)

Comment: There is a lot of trouble associated with Joda on mobile platform. Take your case for example. I am not criticizing Joda, but I find Java libraries equally impressive.

Comment: I understand that with joda are some problems like this, but Java libraries are really much slower - I did my benchmarks, I read it over internet, or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044107/migrating-from-java-calendar-to-joda-date-time.  They are not equal with joda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Actually adding **joda-convert.jar** to build path works, but only for older version (1.4 and lower, if you download latest one - 1.5 **joda-convert.jar**, it doesn't work)...

Comment: so how did you solve it? only removing joda-convert ?

Comment: exactly like I said, I wrote it quite clear in 2 lines I think :) I fixed it by using older joda-convert.jar

Comment: Apparently, this is still an issue. Using version 1.4 of joda-convert also fixed it for me. The jar can be downloaded from Maven Central here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.joda%7Cjoda-convert%7C1.4%7Cjar

Comment: Fixed mine: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.4/joda-convert-1.4.jar